# If next cell text matches current cell text then return adjacent value in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to come up with a script or formula that takes multiple cells with similar text and returns the values of the adjacent cell in a specific format.

Example:

```
A          |            B
-----------------------------
123        | Sample String I
-----------------------------
456        | Sample String II
-----------------------------
789        | Sample String III
-----------------------------
987        | Sample String IV
-----------------------------
654        | Not String I
-----------------------------
```

In column B, take the string "Sample String" (or whatever word(s)) and get the numbers adjacent to it in column A, then go to the next cell below it in column B and if the words are the same the concatenate the numbers in column A to the output.

The output should be something like:

[Sample String, (123, 456, 789, 987)]

I was thinking of something along the lines of, `if B=LIKE(next cell then CONCATENATE ADJACENT Cell(A), Output Cell(C)`

An issue is that there are hundreds of these repeating, almost but not exactly, and I have multiple workbooks to go through. So I was also thinking maybe there is a way to compare the text and if the text matches more than 70% then do this otherwise create a new entry or something. I really have no idea though. If there are other programs that might be able to do this better then I'm open to ideas.

Comment: [`Fuzzy LookUp`](http://www.excel-university.com/perform-approximate-match-and-fuzzy-lookup-in-excel/) may help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel Just introduced TEXTJOIN() in the most recent Office 365 update and Online app:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sample String",$B$1:$B$5)),$A$1:$A$5,""))
```

[image]

---

For earlier versions Put in C1 and copy down:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(B2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","}}}",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))-1),B1)),A1&"," &C2,A1)
```

[image]

This will make the first of each new substring the correct value.  Then using a VLOOKUP() like:

```
=VLOOKUP("Sample Strin" & "*",$B$1:$C$5,2,FALSE)
```

Will return the correct value:

[image]

Comment: great formula if user has latest office version ... and if you can find a way to work against multiple possible matches.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I've got the latest O365 at work so it's a pretty good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Instr()`

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, s As String, f As String

    s = "Sample String"
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & LstRw)
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If InStr(c, s) Then
            f = f & c.Offset(0, -1) & ","
        End If
    Next c
    MsgBox Mid(f, 1, Len(f) - 1)


End Sub
```